# Determining which Access listbox row is selected on click

Tags: ms-access, vba

In MS Access 2016, is it possible to determine which row has been selected at the point the listbox has been clicked.

I've tried something like this

```
With Me.lstSector
    For lngRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(lngRow) Then
        End If
    Next lngRow
End With
```

on the Click event of the listbox, but Access does not seem to be registering any rows are selected

Comment: is it a multi-selection listbox?

Comment: @ThomasG No, single.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is valid, but only if the property Multiselect is true

For a single selection listbox, just do this

```
Me.lstSector.value 'get the value
Me.lstSector.listindex ' get the index
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems fine. However, the On Click event occurs too early (when the box is clicked, before anything changes).

Try using the After Update event.

The code shared by Thomas G should work for that event, but your current code should work as well.